# Is it possible to reload the CLR?

Tags: .net, clr, clr-hosting

I'm fiddling with a project where the CLR is hosted within a C application. Is there a supported way to unlink the CLR and relaunch it?

Comment: Why do you want to reload?  In the IIS model, the unit of reloading/recycling is the worker process itself.  I don't know about SQLCLR, but I suspect there's something more interesting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the book before my right now, but I believe (accroding to [Customization the Common Language Runtime](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619883)) it is not possible to do that. You can unload, i.e. "disable" it, but then you cannot reload it in the same process instance.

Comment: That's true and it's a pain (especially for unit testing CLR hosting code!)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to reload the CLR, you could load and host all of your information in an [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) you create.

You could then manage the life of the AppDomain, including unloading the entire AppDomain and loading a new one.

This will provide most of the benefits that reloading the CLR would provide, without actually trying to unload the CLR.